# Add video to konvajs stage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

I have a working web functionality that uses html5 video and canvas to access the mediaStream of the device camera then take a photo and render the image in the canvas. Works well but I would like to use konvajs stage instead of canvas.

The code

```
    I created a new konva image object:

      var video = new Konva.Image({
      node:video,
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
     image: vidObj,
     width: 300,
     height: 300
    });
```

The complete code is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/63qbt12b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to draw video into canvas element, then use this canvas as source for `Konva.Image`:

```
// create canvas
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

var vidObj = new Image();
var snap = layer.findOne('.snap');
if (!snap) {
    snap = new Konva.Image({
      image: canvas,
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      name: 'snap'
    });
    layer.add(snap);
}
snap.image(canvas);
layer.draw();
```

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Video_On_Canvas.html

Comment: Thank you lavrton! Your solution is clean and works great!